# Chrome and Firefox handle zoom differently. How to deal with this in my CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

I am building a webpage with a logo and menu in the header. When I zoom out or in, some menu items jump onto a second row, when they are meant to stay on a single row. This happens in Chrome, but does not happen in Firefox.

To illustrate this, I've taken a snippet of my code. The following HTML and CSS creates a blue box with 8 menu items in it. When I zoom in or out in Firefox there are always 8 menu items on a single row, no matter how many zooms I apply. However, if I zoom out several times in Chrome, sometimes the last menu item will jump to the second row. The row of menu items is changing width relative to the width of the menu box (whereas in Firefox the ratio of widths remains the same).

I think the best way to understand what I'm talking about is to view the following code in Chrome and in Firefox, and zoom in and out several times in both to see what happens.

I want what is happening in Firefox to be replicated in Chrome. Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
<head>
  <style>
  #header {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 96px;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  } 
  #menu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 119px;
  }
  #menu li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 8px 0 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font: 14px/27px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
      <li>menu item 1</li>
      <li>menu item 2</li>
      <li>menu item 3</li>
      <li>menu item 4</li>
      <li>menu item 5</li>
      <li>menu item 6</li>
      <li>menu item 7</li>
      <li>menu item 8</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For best results, include a link to a "live demo" (e.g. on jsfiddle or similar).

Comment: Mmm, you're html code is not valid. You have to wrap `<li>`s in `<ul>`.

Comment: @pst: sorry, I've never posted a HTML/CSS question before, or used jsfiddle. Have added it here: http://jsfiddle.net/MLTmE/

Comment: @elclanrs: ok, i've added the <ul> tags

Comment: I might cop some flak for this, but spending excessive amounts of time trying to get your website working under different browsers "zoom" functions is a waste of time. It will never look good. I have never seen a website that "scales" well if it is more complex than a couple of images and buttons (like google starts page).

Comment: Maybe you're right, but at the moment one of my menu items jumps out of the header, which feels amateurish.

Also, take a look at www.bbc.co.uk for a page that scales pretty well in my opinion (in both Firefox and Chrome)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

adding white-space:nowrap; to #menu keeps all menu items in one line during zoom, which means that my site now looks ok. However, chrome and firefox still behave differently under zoom, but i guess that's just something that developers have to allow for.

Comment: I guess so, I misunderstood your original question, but I guess the zoom is something that is native to each browser as there are most likely no standards for zoom.

Comment: my saviour!  +1, a thousand times +1!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your problem by adding in a CSS reset at the top of all of the CSS code.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/03/reset-revisited/